# Submitting data using ajax to refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have successfully used ajax to refresh in-line, via ajax, a contact form. I'm having a bit more difficulty getting it to work with data being sent to mysql. I appreciate that what I have so far is not intended to be refreshed via ajax so it might need some work. Here's what I've got... and any help is appreciated.

Form

```
<form name="email_list" action="">

<p><strong>Your Email Address:</strong><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="40">
<input type="hidden" name="sub" id="sub" value="sub">

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" class="email_submit"></p>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {    
$('.email_submit').submit(function() { 

var email = $("input#email").val();  
            if (name == "") { 
            $("input#email").focus();  
            return false;
        }  
var sub = $("input#sub").val();  
            if (name == "") {  
            $("input#sub").focus();  
            return false;
        }       

var dataString = $(this).serialize();

//alert (dataString);return false;  
/*$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "mailing_list_add2.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() {  
        $('#display_block')                      
        .hide()  
        .fadeIn(2500, function() {  
            $('#display_block');  
        }); 
    }  
}); 
return false; 
});*/

});
```

PHP

```
<?php
// connects the database access information this file
include("mailing_list_include.php");

// the following code relates to mailing list signups only
if (($_POST) && ($_POST["action"] == "sub")) {

if ($_POST["email"] == "") {
        header("Location: mailing_list_add.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        // connect to database
        doDB();

        // filtering out anything that isn't an email address
        if ( filter_var(($_POST["email"]), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  == TRUE) {
            echo '';
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid Email Address';
            exit;
        }

        // check that the email is in the database
        emailChecker($_POST["email"]);

        // get number of results and do action
        if (mysqli_num_rows($check_res) < 1) {
            // free result
            mysqli_free_result($check_res); 

            // cleans all input variables at once
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);

            // add record
            $add_sql =  "INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES('$email')";
            $add_res =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_sql)
                        or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            $display_block = "<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>";

            // close connection to mysql
            mysqli_close($mysqli);
        } else {
            // print failure message
            $display_block = "You're email address - ".$_POST["email"]." - is already subscribed.";
    }
}
}

?>
<html>
<?php echo "$display_block";?>
</html>
```

**Updated above after making changes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems, like:

1. You need to attach the javascript to an event (the form submit), so the first part would be something like:

   `$('form').submit(function() {`
2. You need to send in all (correct...) form values, not just the email address for your php to work:

   `$('form').submit(function() {`

   ```
      var dataString = $(this).serialize();
   ```

Comment: Ok, I think I've tried adapting something else to work and that's not the best approach. Thanks.

Comment: What's annoying is that I have the PHP part working fine and the code works. Apart from the JQuery so I can't stop the page refreshing. Frustrating.

Comment: @Andy Why don't you just comment out the whole ajax call and start with the form event handler? Note that you need to return false from the form event handler to avoid the form getting submitted the normal way.

Comment: I've updated the code for the form and jquery above. The ajax call is commented out and now the url string contains the email being submitted and the other field specifying that this is a submitted address.

Answer (score 0):

you miss the data from the server (remove the HTML tags in your server skript):

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "mailing_list_add.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function(data) {  
            $('#email_add').html("<div id='response'></div>");  
            $('#response').html("<h2>Successfully added to the database.")                      
            .hide()  
            .fadeIn(2500, function() {  
                $('#response').html(data);  
            }); 
        }  
    });
```